# Not Able to generate refresh token for the first time, able to generate using multiple attempts on API (connect/token)

Tags: c#, iis, oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

Trying to generate `access_token` using refresh token but getting `invalid_grant` for couple of times. However, the same API is giving the `access_token` after multiple attempts.
We are not facing this issue on our staging server where we have only one instance. This is coming on our production server only where we have more than one instances.

The problem is, ideally it should not give the `access_token` once we got `invalid_grant` but the same `refresh_token` after multiple retries ends up giving the `access_token` eventually. The `grant_type` I am using is `refresh_token`.

I have tried syncing the NTP time, setting the refresh token lifetime, going on all the instance where our service is deployed and checked which one is giving `invalid_grant` but the one who is giving `invalid_grant` is giving `access_token` also.

**Expected:**

> {
>       "access_token": "xx",
>       "expires_in": 3600,
>       "token_type": "Bearer",
>       "refresh_token": "xz" }

**Getting:**

> {"error": "invalid_grant"}

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen here (with this question)?

Comment: I am expecting a refresh token on the first call only.
Also since i am getting error refresh token is invalid , I should not get refresh token after some attempts , which is weird.

Comment: I meant that with no way to reproduce your issue, how can we be expected to help you?